# Customize type of tab in SendEnvelope API

Tags: docusignapi, api-design

I'm working on creating a program that will send a DocuSign document to customers to have them sign, and to do this, the program will send a PDF with several SignHere tabs that indicate what information should be filled in.

I created several SignHere objects that create signature blocks where the users will sign, as well as custom text boxes for additional information (address, phone, etc), but I want the custom text boxes to be custom boxes, not signature boxes.

Here's what each SignHere object looks like:

```
SignHere userSignature = new SignHere
{ DocumentId = "1", PageNumber = "2", RecipientId = "2",
  TabLabel = "Sign Here", XPosition = "69", YPosition = "120"
};

SignHere userNameField = new SignHere
{ DocumentId = "1", PageNumber = "2", RecipientId = "2",
  TabLabel = "Full Name", XPosition = "69", YPosition = "178"
};

SignHere userTitleField = new SignHere
{ DocumentId = "1", PageNumber = "2", RecipientId = "2",
  TabLabel = "Title", XPosition = "69", YPosition = "217"
};
```

and so on.  I've tried looking in the SignHere definition, but I can't find a way to define what sort of tab appears in these locations.  Is there a way to control this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Text tab, not SignHere for what you are trying to do.